# AngularJS infinite loop on scope function call

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

i am new in the AngularJS programming.So I call getDevice() scope function in my html and I seem to get in infinite loop.Console log:

```
angular.js:14800 Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.9/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
    at angular.js:88
    at m.$digest (angular.js:18418)
    at m.$apply (angular.js:18649)
    at l (angular.js:12627)
    at t (angular.js:12871)
    at XMLHttpRequest.A.onerror (angular.js:12799)
```

Code:
App.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('myController', function($scope, $location, $http)
{
    $scope.getDevice = function(deviceId)
    {
        $http.get('http://localhost:8080/client/' + deviceId + '/receive/device')
        .then(function (response)
        {
            $scope.jsondata = response.data;
        })
        console.log("working");
    };

});
```

html

```
<body>
        <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController"> 
        {{getDevice("elsysDev")}}
        </div>
</body>
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Call function in your controller side just print jsondata to html side

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really wanted to call the method in the view use `ng-init`

> Note: `ng-init` is fired only once

```
<body>
     <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController" ng-init="getDevice('elsysDev')"> 
     </div>
</body>
```